# Derive a formula for a function F

Tags: functions, euclidean-geometry

> Let $S$ := {$(x, y) ∈ \mathbb R^2: x^2 + y^2 = 1$} be the unit circle. Let $p = (0, -1)$ ∈ $S$.
>
> Define a map $F$ from $\mathbb R$ × {$0$} to $S$ as follows: Given $(t, 0)$, let $F((t, 0)) = (x, y)$ ∈ $S$ be the intersection of $S$ with the line through $p$ and $(t, 0)$.
>
> Derive a formula for $F$.
>
> Show that $t$ → $F((t, 0))$ is a bijective map from $\mathbb R$ to $S$ \ {$p$}, and also derive a formula for its
> inverse.

How to derive a formula for $F$? If I get the line passing through $p$ and $(t,0)$, I get $(D): y = at-1$, right?

And I know that to show that $\phi$ : $\mathbb R$ →  $S$ \ {$p$}, I have to show that $\phi$ is injective and surjective.

Please I need help solving this

Comment: $t$ is fixed. So, $y = at-1$ is not a line. Or what is $a$?

Comment: $a$ is the slope

Comment: Slope of what? Your task is to find it. And -- as I said -- $t$ is fixed. So, $y = at-1$ is a constant, not a line.

Comment: You have a line that passes through $(t,0)$ and $(0,-1)$. I hope you are able to find the formula for the line. It has the form $z=as+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are to be found.

Answer (score 0):

For a start: From the intercept theorem we have
$$\frac y1=\frac{\sqrt{(x-t)^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}.$$
Squaring and using $x^2+y^2=1$ we arrive in
$$y^2=\frac{(t-1)^2}{1+t^2}.$$

Comment: and what this tell me about the formula of F?

Comment: Just complete the start I gave you, please.

Comment: I dont know what to do

Comment: You basically know the $y$ already by taking the appropriate square root.  From $x^2+y^2=1$ calculate $x$.

Comment: ok so then $y = \frac{|t-1|}{1+t^2}$? and $x = \sqrt(1- \frac{(t-1)^2}{1+t^2})$, and then how do I get the formula of F?

Comment: That *is* $F$, provided you choose the signs right: you have to take the negative root for $y$, e.g.

Comment: so the formula of $F$ is $F = (\frac{\sqrt(2t)}{\sqrt(1+t^2)}, \frac{1-t}{1+t^2})$?

Answer (score 0):

If we express $S$ in polar coordinates:

$$S:=\{(r,\varphi):r=1,\varphi∈(-\frac\pi{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})\}$$

then, from simple trigonometric relations, the inverse function $\Phi$ is:

$$\Phi(\varphi)=\tan\frac{\frac\pi2-\varphi}2$$

and its inverse $F$ is:

$$F(t)=\frac\pi{2}-2\arctan t$$

After changing coordinates back to cartesian, $F$ will look like:

$$F(t)=(\cos(\frac\pi{2}-2\arctan t),\sin(\frac\pi{2}-2\arctan t))$$

which can be further simplified to:

$$F(t)=(\frac{2 t}{t^2 + 1},\frac{1 - t^2}{t^2 + 1})$$

Comment: and so this is the formula of F?

Comment: Remark: $F$ is not the inverse.

Comment: @JOJO $F$ is _the_ function, or the inverse of the inverse